# JSF2 Richfaces 4: onclick event lost from client side queue when focus is in h:inputText which executes an onchange

Tags: javascript, dom-events, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I have the following code (simplified):

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="myDateField">
        <a4j:ajax event="onchange" listener="${myListener}" render="myValidateButton"/>
    </h:inputText>
    
    <a4j:commandButton id="myValidateButton" value="Validate" action="validate" disabled="#{not isActive}" />
</h:form>
```

When I change the value of `myDateField`, I leave the cursor on that field and then click on Validate. The `onchange` event of the input text is executed, but the `onclick` event of the Validate button never reaches the server. I logged the events in the queue on the client side, I can see that the click event on the Validate button is pushed into the queue but never dequeued.

The `onclick` works well if I remove the render of the Validate button in the input text `onchange` event but I need the refresh to know if I must enable or disable the Validate button.

I can understand that the refresh causes the death of the click event.

The `keyup` event worked well for other fields because I can send intermediate input, then the click will not interfere with the `keyup` event. But in the case of a date field, I can't use `keyup` event because I must send the whole date.

Any help please?

Comment: You can edit the question. What you add in comments may not be read by all.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are the conditions for disabling the button?

Comment: In the normal condition, when clicked, the myValidateButton executes an action in ther server side and disables itself. Any changes detected in the inputs of the form, will enable the button. But when I change the value of the myDateField input which listen to the onchange event and, before I leave the input, I click on my enabled myValidateButton  button, the browser will fire 2 events: onchange event of the input then the onclick of the myValidateButton. The first event will be processed by richfaces and the second will be ignored.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for disabling the button? Or for having that button at all, you can validate with the onchange listener.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Validation is not about checking the correctness of data, it'is an action that executes in the server side and without leaving the page. Disabling button is just an indication for the end user that there is no modification in the current page.

Comment: The `onchange` listener is already executing some action on the server, I don't understand why you need execute a second action when you can do it as part of the first action.

Comment: The on click on the button fires automatically 2 events: since the focus is in the modified input before the click, the click will cause the lose of the focus on the input, therefore the execution of the onchange event registered on that input. This is the first event. The second event is the click ==> a click fires 2 events. It worked well before the migration from RF3.3 to RF 4.5.